# Do I use the same format for pack as I did with unpack?

Tags: php, pack

I used `unpack()` to make my `binary[]` from C# into an array of something? To push it to the database with a `POST`. But with my `GET`, I want to send back the `byte[]` or now a medium blob from the database.
Do I use the same format with `pack()` as I did with `unpack()`?

```
$arrData = unpack("H*hex", $bytes);
$content = "0x" . $arrData['hex'];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the same format, but without the name suffix.

```
$arrData = unpack("H*hex", $bytes);

$bytes = pack('H*', $arrData['hex']); // H* only
```